# PHP-CSS-HTML applying a class to a tag through php with templates

Tags: php, class, include, task-parallel-library

As you will guess i'm new to php. Thanks for your help.
I have this piece of code in a header tpl:

```
<div class="menu">
            <ul>                                                                         
                <li class="selected"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">carta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">delicias artesanas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">d&oacute;nde estamos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

which I'd like to call with PHP function include.
The thing is, I want to call this tpl, indicating which one of the li's will have the "selected" class applied, how can I do that?
As I told you, easy peasy for anyone with basic PHP experience.
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base it off of a variable that is set in your calling (non-template) logic. For instance, in smarty you could do this in the PHP:

```
// Determine which section user is in and pass to tpl
$smarty->assign('location', 'home');
```

Then in your template you can just check that variable:

```
<li{if $location eq 'home'} class="selected"{/if}><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li{if $location eq 'carta'} class="selected"{/if}><a href="#">carta</a></li>
```

The keeps HTML out of your biz logic (PHP) and in your display logic (tpl).

Comment: finally, I used {include file="tpl/menu.tpl" location="home"}

Answer (score 0):

make a function for that:

```
function menu($selected = null) {
    echo '<ul class="menu">';
    $options = array('home', 'carta', 'delicias artesanas', 'contact', 'd&oacute;nde estamos');
    foreach ($options as $li) {
        echo '<li' . ($li == $selected ? ' class="selected"' : '').'><a href="#">'.$li.'</a></li>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

and then just call it later:

```
menu('d&oacute;nde estamos');
```